# Improving 10001st prime number project

Tags: java, primes

I have been working on a Project Euler problem which is to find the 10001st prime number. I made the project in java and it gave me the correct answer. I couldn't help but notice that it had taken 17 seconds to find the answer. I am fairly new to java and I would appreciate feedback on how to improve the efficiency of my Java program - at the moment it is bruteforce.

```
static boolean isPrime;  
static int primeCount;  
static int forI = 1;  
static int latestPrime;  

public static void main(String[] args){  
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();  
    while(primeCount < 10001){  
        isPrime = true;  
        forI++;  
        for(int i = forI - 1; i > 1; i--){  
            //If forI is divisible by another number < forI, it is not prime  
            if(forI % i == 0){  
                isPrime = false;  
            }  
        }  
        if(isPrime){  
            primeCount++;  
            latestPrime = forI;  
        }  
    }  
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;  
    System.out.println(primeCount+" "+latestPrime);  
    System.out.println("Time taken: " + endTime / 1000 + " seconds");  
}
```

Comment: a) you don't abort your for() loop when you do find a divisor, so you keep testing all OTHER possible divisors, wasting time. b) you're testing too large of a range for each number - you only need to test up to sqrt(number_being_tested). You're testing ALL possible divisors, including even ones. c) Since 2 is the only even prime, all other even divisors are impossible.

Comment: To clarify @MarcB's "a)": Change the for-loop header to `for(int i = forI - 1; i > 1 && isPrime; i--){`...I think `isPrime`, and not `!isPrime`...

Comment: Please remove the answer to the project euler question! Also, this question seems off-topic for stackoverflow - but would likely be on-topic for the [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) stack.

Comment: @MarcB Thank you, I was planning to break out of the for loop, but forgot, I will add that in. Is there a better, non-bruteforce way of doing this, or would this be considered the 'good practise'?

Comment: Also you can check the forum on the problem 7 (at the right of the question (if you solved it)). A lot of smart and useful optimizations are discussed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check out the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Basically, for each number you are checking whether or not its prime by checking every single number less than it divides it evenly, this is very inefficient.

For an easy improvement, you only need to check all divisors less than the **square root** of the number.

Comment: This answer is at best incomplete, at worst it is misleading. The algorithm linked is very distinct both in concept and implementation, to the one the OP implemented. It's not just a matter of checking only "up to the square root". This is blatantly false.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NewNthPrime{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean flag = false;
        int max = 10002;
        int[] a = new int[max];
        a[0] = 2;
        int i = 3,j=0;
        int t = in.nextInt();
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
            int n = in.nextInt();
            while(j<n){
                for(int y=0;y<a.length;y++){
                    if(a[y]==0){
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (i%a[y]==0){
                        flag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!flag){
                    a[++j]=i;
                }
                flag =false;
                i+=2;
            }
            System.out.println(a[n-1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does, how it works, and what user input it expects.